# how to get a part of a char array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am new in C and I have the following simple code. I know that with the strncpy I can copy characters from string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str1[]= "To be or not to be";
  char str2[40];

  strncpy ( str2, str1, 5 );
  str2[5] = '\0';   /* null character manually added */
  puts (str2);

  return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is

```
To be
```

If I want the result to be ´or not to´ how can I read these characters? From 7-15 in this case?

Comment: stop using c-style strings in c++ and use the [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). it has `find_first_of` or `at()` which can help you

Comment: I need an answer for this example..So in C..Sorry about that

Comment: Removed the `c++` tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use :

```
  strncpy ( str2, str1+6, 9);
  str2[9] = '\0';   /* null character manually added */
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to count manually ,you can use standard library function for this.Try like following

```
strncpy ( str2, str1+strlen("To be "), strlen("or not to") );
str2[strlen("or not to")] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do that, offset `str1`:

```
strncpy ( str2, str1 + 6, 9 );
```